# Check if correct username/password from HTTP response in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, http

In Android/Java I have a requirement where with the username and password I hit a particular site and get the reponse.

I am able to get that reponse. But from that response how would I know if I have entered the correct username/password. As I get response for both correct and wrong username/password.

I have response and cookies with me. From these how can I know if wht I have entered is correct username/password.

This is the code that I am using.

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
httpGet.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, httpContext);
```

Here in `response` I am getting the same content for correct and wrong username/password

Comment: For both correct and wrong username/password you get same response code from server?

Comment: Are you getting same response in both case correct and wrong username/password?

Comment: I am getting the response code which has lot of details in both the cases. From there how to differentiate for correct and wrong Username/Password.

Comment: Kindly dont votedown the question. This is a genuine problem I am facing. Please consider this question and vote up for it. If u need some other details I am ready to share with regard to this issue that I am facing.

Comment: what code have you implemented so far to make web call? And status code means 200 (successful web call), 400, 401 or else?

Comment: @saichandra557 you should provide enough detail with request and response structure of your webservice and also detailed description of your problem.

Comment: You're not providing enough information for anybody to help you--we can't see over your shoulder, so we have no idea what information you're getting back from which to determine good/bad login. If the page URL is the same for success/failure you'll likely need to parse/grep the returned HTML for known error/success messages.

Comment: Just check response code for both correct and wrong, you have deffenetly get solution from response code if server handles that response appropriately.

Comment: @PareshMayani Yes I am getting 200 in both the cases. That is the reason I am not able to differentiate.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for ur feedback. I would improve my question.  I am getting a HTTP response on good and bad login. Response seems to be similar in both the cases. That is the reason I am not able to differentiate.

Comment: update the question with code that you are using right now

Comment: @saichandra557 It's not the status code you'd use for this--it's the contents of the response. The status code indicates success/response of the HTTP call *itself*, not how an application responds to login failures.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the response. So, from the HTTP response is there a parameter that tells if the login has been successful or not? Kindly update.

Comment: @saichandra557 The content of the response, in other words, "the stuff shown on the browser page", the "view source", the HTML.

Comment: @DaveNewton I understand ur answer. But here I should not redirect to the webpage. I wont have any HTML page. What I have is reponse from Httpresponse class. From the parameters of this class I want to know how to capture wrong Username/Password scenario.

Comment: @saichandra557 And I'm saying that information is almost certainly not in the response headers, it will be in the response *body*. [See the HttpClient intro for details.](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server has its logic to deal with in/correct username/password, but typically, this is done via the response body, not the response headers.  About the only time the 401 response code is used, is when a site uses domain (NTML) credentials and either they haven't been supplied or they were incorrect.

The difference being that NTML authentication is done by the browser, and so it knows how to ask for the username/password, while the more typical forms based authentication is done by the server asking for and then validating the input - the browser really doesn't understand what kind of request is being made, it is just submitting some form data, and the server then responds to that with some data: for :) or :(.  The browser treats both contents the same way.